# VHDL: Reading a text file

Tags: text, vhdl

I know that it is possible to read text files in VHDL as a simulation. But is it possible to read a text file and store it in bits in a register? What I want to achieve is to read some data from a text file and use them as input for a combinational circuit after storing them in a register.

Comment: Please, try something and post it here so we can help you with the actual problems your code has. What you are asking can be achieved with multiple ways and hopefully you can find a lot of good examples in the internet if you search a little bit :)

Comment: Thank you for your response! What I want to achieve is to directly read the data from a text file through VHDL module synchronously with a clock and do synthesis. As you have pointed out, there were numerous examples for reading from a text file, but most of them were to be used as benchmark. I want use these data to determine the states of my FPGA board

Comment: If you expect a file read at runtime to be synthesisable,  just forget it.  The one exception may be that some tools will support reading a file at synthesis time and embedding its contents in e.g. a ROM. So, still not at run time. (And easier , less hassle and more portable to embed the contents in a VHDL file that declares a constant array, thus eliminating the file read part)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a question. Seeing somebody else asked this same question on the same day: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43968200/vhdl-reading-from-a-text-file , it seems this is a homework assignment?

Comment: When you are coding hardware, first draw a picture of the hardware you want.   What is the hardware implication of reading a file?   Do you intend to use the same file every time the chip runs?   That would be a ROM.   Do you intend to read different files for different situations?   That means you need to define an interface to read the file into your chip for processing.